# What do you call a graph that has vertex groups?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, directed-graphs

I was wondering what to call a graph that can have a group of vertices as one vertex while at the same time allowing individual vertices in the group to be linked to other vertices in the graph. Here is a figure to illustrate:

[image: example graph]

In the example figure, note the following:

- we cannot have 2 edges from a and b to c. The semantics here is: the (a,b) group has to be linked to C and not a and b individually.
- we can have the group act as one vertex ((d,e) -> f) and we can have a subset of the group to act as one vertex as well (c -> e)
- let's assume we are only dealing with a directed graph
- let's assume the group cannot have an inward edge (the destination of every edge is a single vertex)

This cannot be represented as a hypergraph because the vertices inside a group are never linked together.

What I have in mind: we can look at this graph as a directed graph that can have vertex groups (including those that with 1 vertex). So every vertex becomes a vertex group, and then the notation would be: G(V, S, E). V is the set of individual vertices, S is the set of vertex groups defined over V, and E is the set of edges connecting v -> w s.t. v and w are in S. Does this seem sound?

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: You're showing it as a directed graph, is that relevant to the restrictions you envisage on structure?

Comment: Yes, let's assume it's a directed graph. Edited the question.

Comment: Specifically, it seems like vertices within  group cannot have an outward edge but can attach an inward edge - is this accurate? Can the group as a whole accept an inward edge?

Comment: Where I'm going is that each vertex group looks to me like some kind of processing layer, which could be modelled as $n$ "acceptor" vertices and one "emitter" vertex (which you show as the dotted surround); the acceptors all have only one out-edge to the emitter, which itself only has in-edges from the acceptors.

Comment: let's assume the group cannot have an inward edge (the destination of every edge is a single vertex)

Comment: Thanks, @Joffan. Do you have links to documentation about these types of graphs? Anything would help because I had never come across those types of graphs.

Comment: It's got elements of a dendrogram in the version I'm imagining, but there's also a general graphing aspect. It's interesting; if I come across useful terminology I'll try to gather it in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a directed hypergraph.

Each edge of a directed hypergraph is a pair of subsets of the vertex sets: a "tail subset" and a "head subset". We think of the hyperedge as going from the tail subset to the head subset.

In the example you drew, the three edges are

- an edge with tail $\{a,b\}$ and head $\{c\}$
- an edge with tail $\{c\}$ and head $\{d\}$
- an edge with tail $\{d,e\}$ and head $\{f\}$.

Comment: Excellent answer! I am reading more about directed hypergraphs right now.